# PostgreSQL multi-layer partitioning

Tags: database, postgresql, partitioning, multi-level

I have been using partitioning with a postgreSQL database for a while. My database has grown quite a lot and does so nicely with partitioning. Unfortunately I now seem to have hit another barrier in speed and am trying to figure out some ways to speed up the database even more.

My basic setup is as follows:
I have one master table called `database_data` from which all the partitions inherit. I chose to have one partition per month and name them like: `database_data_YYYY_MM` which works nicely.

By analyzing my data usage, I noticed, that I mostly do insert operations on the table and only some updates. The updates, however also occur on only a certain kind of row: I have a column called `channel_id` (a FK to another table). The rows I update always have a `channel_id` out of a set of maybe 50 IDs, so this would be a great way of distinguishing the rows that are never updated from the ones that potentially are.

I figured it would speed up my setup further if I would use the partitioning to have one table of *insert only* data and one of *potentially updated* data per month, as my updates would have to check less rows each time.

I could of course use the "simple" partitioning I am using now and add another table for each month called `database_data_YYYY_MM_update` and add the special constraints to that and the `database_data_YYYY_MM` table in order for the query planner to distinguish between the tables.

I was, however thinking, that I do sometimes have operations which operate on all data of a given month, no matter if updateable or not. In such a case I could JOIN the two tables but there could be an easier way for such queries.

So now to my real question:

Is "two layer" partitioning possible in PostgreSQL? What I mean by that is, that instead of having two tables for each month inheriting from the master table, I would only have one table per month directly inheriting from the master table e.g. `database_data_YYYY_MM` and then have two more tables inheriting from that table, one for the insert only data e.g. `database_data_YYYY_MM_insert` and one for the updateable data e.g. `database_data_YYYY_MM_update`.

Would this speed up the query planning at all? I would guess that it would be faster if the query planner could eliminate both tables at once if the intermediate table was eliminated.

The obvious advantage here would be that I could operate on all data of one month by simply using the table `database_data_YYYY_MM` and for my updates use the child table directly.

Any drawbacks that I am not thinking of?

Thank you for your thoughts.

---

Edit 1:

I don't think a schema is strictly necessary to answer my question but if it helps understanding I'll provide a sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE database_data (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    channel_id bigint,    -- This is a FK to another table
    timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    value DOUBLE PRECISION
)
```

I have a trigger on the database_data table that generates the partitions on demand:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_insert_database_data() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    thistablename TEXT;
    thisyear INTEGER;
    thismonth INTEGER;
    nextmonth INTEGER;
    nextyear INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- determine year and month of timestamp
    thismonth = extract(month from NEW.timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');
    thisyear = extract(year from NEW.timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');

    -- determine next month for timespan in check constraint
    nextyear = thisyear;
    nextmonth = thismonth + 1;
    if (nextmonth >= 13) THEN
        nextmonth = nextmonth - 12;
        nextyear = nextyear +1;
    END IF;

    -- Assemble the tablename

    thistablename = 'database_datanew_' || thisyear || '_' || thismonth;

    -- We are looping until it's successfull to catch the case when another connection simultaneously creates the table
    -- if that would be the case, we can retry inserting the data
    LOOP
        -- try to insert into table
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(thistablename) || ' SELECT ($1).*' USING NEW;
            -- Return NEW inserts the data into the main table allowing insert statements to return the values like "INSERT INTO ... RETURNING *"
            -- This requires us to use another trigger to delete the data again afterwards
            RETURN NEW;
        -- If the table does not exist, create it
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN UNDEFINED_TABLE THEN
                BEGIN
                    -- Create table with check constraint on timestamp
                    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || thistablename || ' (CHECK ( timestamp >= TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '''|| thisyear || '-'|| thismonth ||'-01 00:00:00+00''
                        AND timestamp < TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '''|| nextyear || '-'|| nextmonth ||'-01 00:00:00+00'' ), PRIMARY KEY (id)
                        ) INHERITS (database_data)';
                    -- Add any trigger and indices to the table you might need
                    -- Insert the new data into the new table
                    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(thistablename) || ' SELECT ($1).*' USING NEW;
                    RETURN NEW;
                EXCEPTION WHEN DUPLICATE_TABLE THEN
                    -- another thread seems to have created the table already. Simply loop again.
                END;
            -- Don't insert anything on other errors
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                RETURN NULL;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_database_data
BEFORE INSERT ON database_data
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_insert_database_data();
```

As for sample data: Let's assume we only have two channels: 1 and 2. 1 is insert only data and 2 is updateable.

My two layer approach would be something like:

Main table:

```
CREATE TABLE database_data (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    channel_id bigint,    -- This is a FK to another table
    timestamp TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    value DOUBLE PRECISION
)
```

Intermediate table:

```
CREATE TABLE database_data_2015_11 (
    (CHECK ( timestamp >= TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2015-11-01 00:00:00+00' AND timestamp < TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2015-12-01 00:00:00+00)),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) INHERITS(database_data);
```

Partitions:

```
CREATE TABLE database_data_2015_11_insert (
    (CHECK (channel_id = 1)),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) INHERITS(database_data_2015_11);

CREATE TABLE database_data_2015_11_update (
    (CHECK (channel_id = 2)),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) INHERITS(database_data_2015_11);
```

Of course I would then need another trigger on the intermediate table to create the child tables on demand.

Comment: Without code, schema and sample data this gets off-topic

Answer (score 0):

It's a clever idea, but sadly it doesn't seem to work. If I have a parent table with 1000 direct children, and I run a `SELECT` that should pull from just one child, then `explain analyze` gives me a planning time of around 16ms. On the other hand, if I have just 10 direct children, and they all have 10 children, and those all have 10 children, I get a query planning time of about 29ms. I was surprised---I really thought it would work!

Here is some ruby code I used to generate my tables:

```
0.upto(999) do |i|
  if i % 100 == 0
    min_group_id = i
    max_group_id = min_group_id + 100
    puts "CREATE TABLE datapoints_#{i}c (check (group_id > #{min_group_id} and group_id <= #{max_group_id})) inherits (datapoints);"
  end
  if i % 10 == 0
    min_group_id = i
    max_group_id = min_group_id + 10
    puts "CREATE TABLE datapoints_#{i}x (check (group_id > #{min_group_id} and group_id <= #{max_group_id})) inherits (datapoints_#{i / 100 * 100}c);"
  end
  puts "CREATE TABLE datapoints_#{i + 1} (check (group_id = #{i + 1})) inherits (datapoints_#{i / 10 * 10}x);"
end
```